# ReactJS - Image is not shown in a custom column of Material-Table

Tags: javascript, reactjs, image, material-table

I'm working on material-table to render a custom column with images just like [this example in the official docs.](https://material-table.com/#/docs/features/custom-column-rendering) But there is a little problem. The example online image [from githubusercontent.com](https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/7895451?s=460&v=4) is working perfectly fine but if I give the path of a local image on my machine it don't work.

**With Image on my machine**

[image]

**With online Image**

[image]

There is no problem with image dimensions or file extension etc. as I downloaded the same image from githunusercontent.com and that is not working on local machine as well.

**Edit**

Just I saw a little error message in the console saying

> Not allowed to load local resource 'file-path'
> What to do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show the image from the local machine you can do it in the following way:

**`App.js`** file:

```js
import React from 'react';

import MaterialTable from 'material-table';

export default class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MaterialTable
        title="Render Image Preview"
        columns={[
          { title: 'Avatar', field: 'imageUrl', render: rowData => <img src={require('./img.jpeg')} style={{ width: 40, borderRadius: '50%' }} /> },
          { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
          { title: 'Surname', field: 'surname' },
          { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type: 'numeric' },
          {
            title: 'Birth Place',
            field: 'birthCity',
            lookup: { 34: 'İstanbul', 63: 'Şanlıurfa' },
          },
        ]}
        data={[
          { name: 'Mehmet', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 1987, birthCity: 63, imageUrl: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/7895451?s=460&v=4' },
          { name: 'Zerya Betül', surname: 'Baran', birthYear: 2017, birthCity: 34, imageUrl: 'https://avatars0.githubusercontent.com/u/7895451?s=460&v=4' },
        ]}
      />
    )
  }
}
```

**Note: I've downloaded the image and renamed it as `img.jpeg` from the URL you've given here and kept it in the same directory where `App.js` file is located.**

Comment: Can I see your `package.json` file? It's working for me. I've checked. It would be better if you provide the code that you've tried.

Comment: Ok Thanks for your time. There might be some other issue like lazy leading or some other stuff like that. I'll check that myself :)

Comment: upvoted for now. Will accept your answer once done on my end as well :)

Comment: It's ok, hope you can figure that out soon. :)

Comment: It worked for me  by reading the Base64String representation of image using Javascript FileReader and assigning that to image src, as New version of Chrome don't allow to use local file paths

Comment: Glad to hear that. Congratulations.